# How to break on document.write in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, document.write

Is there a way to break/trigger debugger on document.write() during page load, without knowing where it's going to occur?

The whole page is blown away by some third party ad provider code, which must be executed without iframe, but I have to find a way to identify the source of these problems.

Comment: If it breaks, you must be getting an error. You can either use pause on exception in dev tools or trace it using stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `document.write()` function :

```
<script language="javascript">
 document.write =(exp1, exp2, exp3, ...)=> {
   console.log('test');
 }
</script>

<!--  Write is then called somewhere-->
<script language="javascript">
 document.write();
</script>
```

**Update**

Another solution would be to use the chrome devtools event listener breakpoints:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But how could I make this persist after page reload, without modifying the .js files, limited to the possibilities of DevTools?